# Passing a hash as arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
user = User.from_google(from_google_params)

  def from_google_params
    @from_google_params ||= {
      uid: auth.uid,
      email: auth.info.email,
      full_name: auth.info.name,
      avatar_url: auth.info.image
    }
  end
```

...and here is the from_google method the hash is being passed to.

```
def self.from_google(email:, full_name:, uid:, avatar_url:)
```

When I run this I am getting an argument error `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0; required keywords: email, full_name, uid, avatar_url)):`

Here is what I see in the console:

```
>> from_google_params.inspect
=> "{:uid=>\"100373362533979950619\", :email=>\"marklocklear@extension.org\", :full_name=>\"Mark Locklear\", :avatar_url=>\"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gh1leKarrW8SCvxxwvaAcDkAISXYQ38k4xPQuC1Rg=s96-c\"}"
>> from_google_params.class
=> Hash
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the double splat operator (**) to convert the hash into keyword arguments.

```
user = User.from_google(**from_google_params)
```

The [separation of keywords and positional arguments](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/) was a big change in Ruby 3. Previous versions of Ruby would coerce the last positional argument into keywords if its a hash - this behavior was depreciated in Ruby 2.7 and removed completely in 3.0.